# Add listener after OK click

Tags: java

Trying to add the current object as an `AcquisitionListener` when the user hits the OK button. However, adding it as a listener works anywhere except inside the block that executes on clicking the OK button:

```
    mainFrame.setOkAction(new ActionListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) //On OK click
        {
            MicroManager.addAcquisitionListener(this);
        }
    }
```

*The method addAcquisitionListener(AcquisitionListener) in the type MicroManager is not applicable for the arguments (new ActionListener(){})*

If I understand correctly, this happens because **This** is now referring  `ActionListener` for the button instead of the class object.

How can I fix this?

Comment: `this` is actually referring to the `ActionListener` instance.  You need to use the outer class as a reference point ie `OutterClass.this`

Comment: @MadProgrammer That's an answer. Why not post it as such?

Comment: Because there’s probably a duplicate somewhere - just to lazy to search 